# mysql request using join and group_concat

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have three tables "names", "groups", "tasks"

"names"

```
| nid | name  |
|  1  | John  |
|  2  | Jim   |
|  3  | Jerry |
```

"groups"

```
| gid | nid |
|  1  |  1  |
|  1  |  2  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  3  |
```

"tasks"

```
| tid | gid |
|  1  |  2  |
|  2  |  1  |
```

I want to get a list of names, that belong to a task, like this:

```
| tid | names     |
|  1  | Jim,Jerry |
|  2  | John,Jim  |
```

I successfully tried:

```
SELECT t.tid,n.name
FROM tasks t
   LEFT JOIN groups g ON g.gid=t.gid
   LEFT JOIN names n ON n.nid=g.nid
```

This works so far, but the names are in single outputs so I tried to use `GROUP_CONCAT()`, but this does not work. I just get the first task with the wrong names!?!?

```
SELECT t.tid,GROUP_CONCAT(n.name)
FROM tasks t
   LEFT JOIN groups g ON g.gid=t.gid
   LEFT JOIN names n ON n.nid=g.nid
```

I have never used `GROUP_CONCAT()` before. It works well, when using it in a single `SELECT` without joins. A short explanation what I did wrong, would be nice.

Comment: add `group by t.tid` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `group_concat` you need to group your results.

Add `group by t.id` at the end of your query.